# How to design tables with cells containing small to large amount of data

Tags: tables

I've got the following data to display:

```
| ID | Participants               | Start Date   |
| 1  | John, Paul, Matthew, John  | 24 Dec. 2010 |
| .. | ...                        | ...          |
```

In the "Participants" column, the amount of possible participants per row ranges from 2 to 20. What concepts or UX best practices can be applied in order to show the data, but not clutter the display too much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be two options. In both options try to make the table structure light, showing just rows:

1. If the all participants are "equal" in importance, just make it more easy to scan through their names by formatting first letters of the names
   [image]
2. If there is some "unequality" between participants, you could point only "stars" but allow to disclose all the participants in a row with `More participants` link:
   [image]

Comment: I like option 2 where a cell transitions into option 1 when you click the link.

Comment: I also depends on how the table is to be used. If you need to be able to quick and easily find a participant, the second option is not a good choice, since it would require a lot of clicks to reveal all participants. If this is the case, then at least add an options to see all participants, so that all the participant in all cells are shown with a single click.